# How to get the location of AxisY and AxisY2 in a Windows Forms Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I need to get the location of AxisY and AxisY2 in a chart. There are a lot of things I would like to do with this information. However, as a simple example, I just want to draw a horizontal line between the two y axes, but not have it extend past them.

Using AxisX.Minimum and Maximum works, as long as all of the values appear on the chart.  However, if the chart has a scroll bar, the lines extend to the left of axisY or the right of axisY2 depending on where the chart is scrolled. Therefore, what I need is the location of AxisY and AxisY2 as displayed.

```
public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add an event handler
    this.chart1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.DrawLine);

    // Add some values
    for (int value = 0; value <= 10; value++)
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(value, value);

    // DrawLine no longer works when a scroll bar is added,
    //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 5);
}

// Draw a line from axisY to axisY2
private void DrawLine(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    // Get the left and right edges of the values
    // This only works if all of the values appear on the chart at the same time, ie. there is no scroll bar
    // How can I find the locations of axisY and axisY2 as drawn on the chart?
    int axisYLocation = (int)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum);
    int axisY2Location = (int)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 5), new Point(axisYLocation, 50), new Point(axisY2Location, 50)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to kirsan31 at [winforms-datavisualization](https://github.com/kirsan31/winforms-datavisualization), this does exactly what I want

```
int axisYLocation = (int)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum);
int axisY2Location = (int)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum);
```